# React Native: Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. SwipeOut component issue

Tags: react-native, components, expo

I am getting this warning with using Swipeout:

"
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See

Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: *** to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles in your project source folder.
Please update the following components: Swipeout
"

Same thing for componentWillMount.

Of note, using npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles does not work to alleviate this error.

I went into the code for Swipeout and manually added the UNSAFE_ but every time I compile the code, it reverts back.

I've opened up an issue with the page on GitHub but no response after several days.

Suggestions?

Thank you,

Comment: while awaiting for an update, you could set up a post-install script to copy the modified file and replace its counterpart under the `node_modules` of Swipeout.

Comment: @singamnv You can replace componentWillrecieveprops with getDerivedstatefromProps in the swipout component under nodemodules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, I'd recommend you fork the project. Make the change, remove the OG package from your dependencies and install your own fork with:

```
npm install <YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME>/<YOUR-REPO-NAME>
```

Oh, and while you're at it, if you've got the time, send them a pull request ;)